# How to identify link label is clicked in my form closing event in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a logout button as link label on my main form so if the user click this
  logout link label yes he is logout successfully.

But the problem is he is closed directly main form without clicking logout
  link label. So then there is no way to write when the user is logout in my
  log file because he didn't click logout link label.

So i want to identify my logout link label in my form_Closing event?

How can i?

Edit :

Under my logout link label:

```
 stopWatch = ApplicationState.CurrentTime.StopWatch;
 stopWatch.Stop();

 var timeSpent = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();

 Application.Exit();
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is a way, remove form's close button by setting **borders to None**

Comment: Maybe it is much better to separate the logout logic from the linkLabel click and just call that function when form is closed directly?

Comment: You're not logging anything in the file in this code as you said earlier in the question?

Comment: Yes i logged from my login form  but the logout code is in my main form.

Comment: I defined a static class for accessing my login username then i used this name in my main form for diisplaying a username.

Comment: Where is the code of your log file? What do you do when user logout share the complete code please.

Comment: @Shaharyar yes it is worked for me according to your suggestion i seperated my logout method. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the situation in 2 ways:

1. Remove form's border so user can not close it directly (but in this one you will have to write some extra code to allow user to **Move** the form).

   ```
   this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
   ```
2. Call logout method or event handler on `form_Closing`

But you should have a separate method of containing complete logic of `Logout` rather than a event handler containing it.

Comment: If i call logout method from my form_closing if he clicked logout linklabel in my log file 2 times notified(wrote) the user is loggedout. right?one is logout linklabel 2nd on will be call on form_closing event.

Comment: That is very simple, set a `bool` flag to identify if user is logged in or not and check it in the first place in your method. If you're getting confused share the code and I'll help you to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the LinkVisited property would help. If it has a true value then the link has been clicked.

Comment: yes i already checked like this. if(linklabel1.LinkVisited==true) but it is alway gives false even clicked linklabel

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form where some action should take place before the user can simply click on the 'X' button and close it, consider implementing the `FormClosing` event handler, using a pattern similar to as follows:

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        // We can ask the user if they want to log out,
        // and if not, we can cancel the closing of the form.
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // System is closing form, automatically log out
        // and allow the form to close.
    }
}
```

This simplifies the program design because now from our link label we can simply attempt to close the form after asking the user if they want to log out:

```
private void linkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // Confirm with user if they want to log out:
    var result = MessageBox.Show(
        "Are you sure you want to log out?", "Confirm Log Out",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // Closing the form executes log-out:
        this.Close();
    }
}
```